# Beginner algebra inequality proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $m+n=1$ and $a<b$, then $bm+an<b$. I have tried inserting the first equation into the inequality and also making a substitution, $b=a+p$, but still could not get a proof. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need $n>0$ for this to work.

Since $a<b$ it follows that $an<bn$.

Since $an<bn$ it follows that $bm+an < bm + bn$.

Since $m+n = 1$ it follows that $bm+bn=b(m+n)=b$.

Putting this together gives $bm+an<bm+bn=b(m+n)=b$.

We conclude that $bn+an < b$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $m=1$ and $n=0$ then $m+n=1$ and $bm+an=b$ then $b<b$!?

The condition mentioned by Fly by Night is important. Also you could write $bm+an\leq b$.